# Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's URI::ParseSearchString?

Tags: php, perl, search-engine, cpan, referrer

I'm doing some work for a client that involves parsing the referrer information from Google et al to target various parts of a page to the user's search keywords.

I noticed that Perl's CPAN has a module called [URI::ParseSearchString](http://search.cpan.org/~sden/URI-ParseSearchString-3.441/lib/URI/ParseSearchString.pm) which seems to do exactly what I need. The problem is, I need to do it in PHP.

So, to avoid reinventing the wheel, does anyone know if there is a library out there for PHP that does the same / similar thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the module. As far as I know, I've never seen something similar for PHP. If you do come across anything, please do let me know.

That being said, I cannot image this being very hard to port to PHP and I can have an attempt at it if you dont find anything similar out there.

Spiros

Comment: Thank you - I was quite surprised when my searches turned up no results! Perhaps a port is the best option; I'll keep you posted on the results of my hunt and if nothing turns up, perhaps we can talk about collaborating on a port?

Comment: I've not begun this piece of work yet, but am looking to get started this week sometime. Will let you know.

Comment: Hi there Spiros - I've done a very basic port of this to PHP over the weekend. I wondered if I could have some contact details for you so we can take this discussion elsewhere? Thanks

Comment: Heya, sorry for the late reply - email me at s dot denaxas at gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is what you are looking for.

You may additionally want to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the search string.

Comment: Thank you - however I will point you to the comment I made on @sdolgy's post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too inefficient or the http_referer isn't showing the full uri ...

```
function parse_uri($uri) {
  if (substr_count('?', $uri) > 0) { 
    $queryString = explode('?', $uri);
    return parse_str($queryString[1]);
  } else { 
    return parse_str($uri);
  }
}


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
        print_r(parse_uri($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
}
```

Comment: Thank you - however, I'm not really looking for advice on how to "roll my own" - the parsing stage is trivial, what I'm looking for is something that contains the knowledge of search engines and their parameters, as ParseSearchString does.